# How to check if one of many locations is within a predefined distance - Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'll try to be concise.

I have, lets say, 1000 fixed point geographical locations (UK Postcodes) in my database.

I have a user who could be anywhere in the UK and he wants to perform an action that boils down to the following:

I am here [current location] - show me all the postcodes (from the database) that are within 5 miles of me.

So far the only way I can think to do this is run each postcode in my DB against the Google Maps API versus the user's current location, stick all of the results into an array and then display only those results where the distance is lower than the defined search radius (Eg. 5 miles).

I think there must be a better way to do this. I do not want to be doing 1000+ Api calls each time a user queries the app.

Answer (score 0):

You could download the Zip Codes with their Coordinates as a csv file e.g. from [geonames](http://www.geonames.org/).
Then read them in a dataframe and apply the vincenty function to get the distance to your point.
Afterwards you just filter with your maximum radius.

Answer (score 0):

So as is usually case, even though I was mulling on this for a few hours last night, I immediately found the solution after posting this question.

What I can do is actually add my locations directly into Google Maps and tag them with a unique identifier that only my app can see.

THEN when I'm (or a user is) searching I pass into the API call their location, their search radius and filter results on my unique Place ID:

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/add-place